# Cannot use DateTime with milliseconds as primary key in MSAccess database

Tags: datetime, ms-access, timestamp, primary-key

I have a software which logs data into a table with current date and time accurate to milliseconds. There is no problem in PostgreSQL and MSSQL Server, but in MDB I have primary key violation. When I look into my table using MS Access, it shows datetimes accurate to seconds.

Could milliseconds be written to MDB at all?

Comment: This came up in a search: [MS Access Can Handle Millisecond Time Values--Really](http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/39046), but it's probably not worth the effort, and not suitable as PK.

Comment: Andre, sorry for I couldn't open the link.

Comment: There should be no problem opening the link from @Andre. But here's the link to the [print version](http://www.devx.com/print/dbzone/Article/39046).

Comment: It seems that at my workplace www.devx.com is blocked entirely. I could access the article with cellphone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DateTime field in Access has seconds as accuracy (it's actually stored as a floating number, but it reports and sets in seconds). If you want to store milliseconds, you could store them in a different field.

You can store the millisecond part of the date/time in an integer field, and then use a composite primary key linking the two fields. I've never heard a solid argument against composite primary keys, but it's odd at best.

Comment: Ok, the MDB case is not really so important in my component, so I will leave MDB without PK at all. If somebody wants to use MDB, will do it at own risk.

Comment: Well, the resolution is in fact to the millisecond as you can see from splendid article linked by @Andre. _However_, that doesn't change the fact, that in Access the underlying data type is a float/double which is the last data type to use as a key.

Comment: @Gustav I meant that with the part in parentheses. As it's actually a floating number, it doesn't have a resolution per se, that's dependent on the amount of characters. A large (= far from the reference date) date/time might not be able to handle single millisecond differences (could try to calculate when that would happen, but my math is not that great)

Comment: It's right that Access reports (or displays) rounded to seconds, but the value can be set and stored with millisecond precision for the entire range of the data type. The article contains a demo application with example data to play with, as well as the required custom functions to handle the conversion. Still, neither of this will make the data type useful for the case of the questioneer.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness it's probably worth mentioning that you *could* save the timestamps as `yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss.fff` in a TEXT(23) column. That column could be used as a primary key, and the values could be sorted and compared directly if the numeric parts were all zero-padded. Date arithmetic would be a bit awkward, however.